# Adding second metro style window to project not possible (Elysium)

Tags: c#, windows-8

Can someone tell me if they also sat with this issue and how you resolved it?

I created my first metro styled form perfectly, it ran perfectly, but
when I added second metro style form, it gives me the errors in the picture attached. I use VS 2010 cos elysium doesn't seem to like VS2012 (or vise versa) on win 7.

[image: Errors when adding second metro style window]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just fixed it...

Copied

```
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
          xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
          xmlns:metro="http://schemas.codeplex.com/elysium"
          xmlns:params="http://schemas.codeplex.com/elysium/params"
          params:Design.Theme="Dark"
          params:Design.AccentBrush="{x:Static metro:AccentBrushes.Blue}"
          params:Design.ContrastBrush="White"
          Title="MainWindow" Height="600" Width="525" ResizeMode="CanMinimize">
```

from main from that works perfectly over to the form that complained.

and I can change what form I want to start with running using the App.xaml